# Should I see bubbles in an opened bottle when carbonating by bottle conditioning?

Tags: carbonation, bottle-conditioning

I have been bottle carbonating for the last 10 days. The temperature has been fairly consistent, between 17 - 20. I can see a little sediment, which suggests fermentation, but I can't see any bubbles, is this normal?

Comment: No bubbles in an unopened bottle? Sounds normal to me. I noticed the same thing in my first batch, but when I tried one, it was nicely carbed.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to hear!

Comment: The sediment may just be trub settling, which may contain yeast, but other things as well (proteins, fats, other heavy materials).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, perfectly normal.  It may be done carbing or it may take a few more days.

Comment: how do you know when it is done?

Comment: You chill one, open it, and taste it!

Comment: I like them apples

Comment: You'll like the beer more.

Comment: One suggestion I heard of, to keep track of carbonation was at the same time as you bottle all of your beer, fill a 500ml plastic bottle leaving a normal gap. Squeeze the bottle so that the beer is level with the brim of the opening. Put the lid on and place it with the rest of your carbonating beer. As the gasses are produced this bottle will gradually expand showing you the progress of the carbonation.

Comment: To be specific, a lot of recipe instructions suggest bottle conditioning for two weeks at room temperature. In my experience, and this seems to be a common refrain, it takes at least three weeks at 70°C (21°C) for bottles to fully carbonated -- and 48 hours of refrigeration if you intend to pop one open right away. Whatever the scientific process is, that is how long it takes to get proper carbonation that is dissolved in the beer. Symptoms of not waiting long enough include gushers when you open bottles, over-foamy beers, head that dissipates, and beers that go flat quickly after pouring.